# Multidimmensional array vs flat array - performance comparison

Tags: c++, c, arrays, performance

Is there any performance issue while using one of below methods? Which is faster (if any)? It would be great if is there any performance tests.

Multidimmentional array:

```
// Using multidimmentional array:
int ****multidim_arr;
// ... initialization, etc. ...
int val = multidim_arr[a][b][c][d];
```

Flat array:

```
// Using flat array (or single array)
int *flat_arr;
// ... initialization, etc. ...
int val2 = flat_arr[a * a_lvl + b * b_lvl + c * c_lvl + d];
```

**UPDATE:**

Arrays have fixed size, but memory is allocated by malloc() function because size is known while program is working.

Comment: write and test... that's the way to be sure. Probably the flat array will be faster, though not by much. A flat array is easier to (de-)allocate anyway

Comment: If the array has fixed size (stack-allocated array) and the original type if preserved (like `int arr[4][2][9][4]`), then probably the multidimensional array is faster, as is carries more type information for the compiler to use in optimizations, compared to a flat array whose indices still needs to be calculated.

Comment: @Elias: I wouldn't be so sure, especially when accessing it sequentially, e.g. iterating over the `d` index. In the former case 'a','b' and 'c' would remain cached, in the latter the whole arithmetic expression would be re-evaluated. But personally, I believe optimizer will optimize away both to the same code.

Comment: @SF.: I'm not sure. My first thought was that a flat array would be faster, but I'm having second thoughts, to be honest. As far as the optimizer goes: that all depends on how the array(s) will be used. However, the OP doesn't declare a standard array, but declares pointers... allocated on the heap

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: ah, yes. Quadruple dereference. If the first array was declared not as `****multidim_arr` but as `multidim arr[SIZE_A][SIZE_B][SIZE_C][SIZE_D]` I'd stand by my previous statement. In this case I'm not really so sure.

Comment: Note that pointer-to-pointer is not the same as a true multidimensional array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with all performance questions, profile and see. But it's quite likely the flat array will be faster. That's because you're not comparing multidimensional array with a flat one - you're comparing an array of pointers to an array of pointers to ... to an array with a flat array.

A multidimensional array would be `int multidim_array[dim1][dim2][dim3][dim4]`. And that could be expected to have the same speed as the flat array. That's because that is *contiguous* in memory.

On the other hand, yours is based on pointers, so each slice resides in a different memory location, which means extra fetches, cache misses etc. This will almost definitely be slower.

Comment: Extra fetches, sure, because of the extra pointer lookups. But each slice of the flat array will also live in a different cache line (assuming this isn't a trivially small inner dimension).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between arrays of pointers and pointers to ints

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you iterate over elements and sizes. The performance in such cases heavily depends on cache performance (hit/miss ratio).

It is very hard to generalize.

The "flat" arrays tend to be faster because access to elements is more direct. You compute the index once. Also by, "flat" I mean continuous memory block, where index  of arbiraty element can be computed in one expression. I would expect `int a[X][Y][Z][W]` to work same fast as `int a[X*Y*Z*W]`, the computation you perform to manually get index is the same as would compielr do.

The real difference is between `int**** a;`

With multi-dimensional "pointer" arrays. This is actually high level pointer reference, and you need to fetch appropriate address on every level. This can impact performance quite hard in certain cases.

Comment: @oli I think I missused the term, thanks for pointing it out. Edited.

Comment: Let's suppose that access to elements is random. How about that?